# How to add column in a data frame with values based on the length of data as as string

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this example

```r
head(iris)
#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#> 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
#> 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
#> 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
dim(iris)
#> [1] 150   5
```

Iris data has 150 rows. What I want to do is to add new column (`Observations`),
resulting in

```r
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species Observations
          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa  Obs_1
          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa  Obs_2
          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa  Obs_3
          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa  Obs_4
          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa  Obs_5
          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa  Obs_6
   ....etc...
```

How can I do that?

Comment: have you tried anything to solve it by yourself? this is skill you can get after reading like 2 pages of any `R` tutorial...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `paste`

```
iris$Observation <- paste0("Obs_", seq_len(nrow(iris)))
```

---

If we are using `tidyverse`, there is `row_number()` function

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>%
     mutate(Observation = paste0("Obs_", row_number()))
```